# How do I create a circular progress bar that I can change the total amount from 100% to any other value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I would like to show a "progress" bar that can represent values such as `10/100`, `2/5`, `50/60`... and so on. So far all the ones I find are usually progress bar where the total is always 100%. so putting something like 110 out of 200 would not be represented properly in a progress bar set at 100%. I hope I'm explaining the problem properly.

I don't have much code to go with this question but I found a codepen example I would like to use but like I mentioned it only goes to 100%.

here's a link to the pen: https://codepen.io/curdwithraisins/pen/aOGEBX

Comment: Try one of those https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: At least for me it is not clear what you are asking here. `110 out of 200 is 55%` What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your Codepen reference to make it fit your requirement.

pass current percentage and total percentage value to the function progressBar.

Example: `progressBar(10,200);`

I hope this resolves your problem: https://codepen.io/sheikzm/pen/BeyXpz

Comment: There was an issue displaying the percentage value... it's fixed now.